# Why I cannot set -Xmx to 1024m in eclipse.ini?

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, jvm

When I try to set -Xmx1024m I receive message:

```
cannot create VM
```

but on my computer near 1500m free. How it is possible?
Thanks.

Comment: You may have 1500m free but it might be too fragmented for the JVM to be allocated a single 1 gig block.

Comment: I don't think that is the diagnosis. It's just the maximum. Are you sure you know how to write eclipse.ini? Do you have -vmargs?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Java will reserve a contiguous space of virtual memory at start up, if virtual memory is too fragmented and no contiguous block of 1 GB is available then Java will stop with an error

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That's interesting, how can virtual memory get fragmented? I'm googling, but not getting anything useful. Can you help me with a good source?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel all I'm getting is that this can be due to DLLs which are loaded into user space, and generally this can be an issue only on a 32-bit system since otherwise the requested 1.5G block can be mapped anywhere inside the vastness of the 64-bit space.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik See https://blogs.oracle.com/moazam/entry/why_can_t_i_allocate (there used to be a better reference, but I can't seem to locate it anymore after the Sun -> Oracle website screwup). I am assuming here that the OP is using a 32 bit JVM.

Comment: Very nice explanation by an authority. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the comments are correct regarding the memory space being too fragmented to allocate a large enough memory block.

See the Eclipse bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=188968.

The fragmentation is generally blamed on windows dlls being loaded into the middle of the address space.  In particular, the splash screen requires loading user32.dll, which in turn can pull in 3rd party libraries depending on what is installed on your machine.

One way to get more memory is to have the JVM forked into a second process instead of running in the eclipse process (which is the default).  This [wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher) details the -vm settings for the eclipse.ini file.  You can force the vm to be forked in a second process by setting -vm to point to a javaw.exe.

This should help because forking the jvm in a second process starts the vm before loading the graphics dlls to show the splash screen.